# "Draught" or "draft"

Tags: orthography

I'm referring to the term used to describe the vertical distance between a ship's keel and the waterline.

Which is the correct spelling: *draught* or *draft*? If either is correct, under which conditions would one be used over the other?

Comment: Interestingly, the same words, with the same regional differences, are also used to describe those chilly little breezes that leak from around poorly sealed windows and doors, and which your mother warned you will cause you to catch cold.

Comment: Don't forget about the usage with beer.

Comment: @Al Everett: Which one? There's the [draught horse](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/draught+horse) used by the [drayman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drayman) to deliver the ale to the pub, and the [draught of ale](http://www.ask.com/questions-about/Meaning-of-Draught) the pub then sells you to drink.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They're just [alternative spellings](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ship%27s%20draft,ship%27s%20draught&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), which overall occur about equally...
[image]

Americans usually spell it *draft* - here's the chart for American-only usage...
[image]

Brits usually use *draught* - here's their usage chart...
[image]

EDIT - Apologies for including yet another chart, but even though they really are just alternative spellings, predominantly associated with the US/UK divide, I find [this American-only usage chart](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=draft%20of%20ale,draught%20of%20ale&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) for *draft/draught of ale* particularly interesting...
[image]

I assume Americans see **ale** as an old-fashioned Britsh word, so they slip into "mock-archaic" spelling (similar to [Ye Olde Tea Shoppe](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ye%20Olde%20Tea%20Shoppe) ). I'll refrain from adding another chart, but conversely [even Brits prefer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=working%20draft,working%20draught&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) *working draft* over *working draught*, because this is a much more recent "set phrase" primarily associated with Americans.

Comment: You should do the graphs separately for the American an British versions. I feel sorry for all the non-AmBrits.

Comment: @Mitch: One day, NGrams will offer choices like "Australian only", though as of today I don't think even their US/UK division is particularly accurate. But it's good enough to prove how indebted US orthography is to Noah Webster!

Comment: It's weird that the usage is so 'bouncy'. Looking at simply the stand-alone word draught/draft, it looks like 'draft' wins in British, too, but that doesn't accord with my experience ('draught' stands out to me as particularly British, never seen in the US). Is 'draft' used in contexts other than nautical in British writing?

Comment: @Mitch although ultimately coming from the same word, the spellings both have distinct meanings in British English. See the note at the bottom of this: http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/draft

Comment: There's also the problem of 'dra[unvoiced labiodental fricative]t' distinguishing: pouring beer, a change to coolness in indoors air, a first version, and rounding up soldiers.

Comment: @z7sgѪ: can you summarize? I don't have OED access.

Comment: I think all that supposed "difference in meaning" amounts to is that some more recent set phrases, such as *working draft*, are primarily American in the first place. So Brits tend towards US spelling, just as Americans go for British spelling with really old phrases such as *draught of ale*.

Answer (score -4):

My answer is *draught horses* and this is how it is spelled in the Australian language.